# tests con administración de conexiones perezosas

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, test

Tengo una conexión a una base de datos cuyas credenciales dependen de una API externa, por lo cual no puede configurar las bases de datos en el settings de mi proyecto django, ya que se trata de diferentes conexiones y que pueden cambiar en cualquier momento.

Debido a esto estoy usando la administración de conexiones perezosas de django, es decir importo de `from django.db import connections` y creo la conexión dentro de mi vista

```
database_params = {
    'ENGINE': 'mssql',
    'NAME': credentials['NAME'],
    'USER': credentials['USER'],
    'PASSWORD': credentials['PASSWORD'],
    'HOST': credentials['HOST'],
    'PORT': credentials['PORT'],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
    },
}
connections.databases[credentials['ID']] = database_params
```

Esto me genera problemas al realizar mis test debido a que se genera un error con el método `tearDownClass` de `APITestCase`

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls._remove_databases_failures()
    if hasattr(cls, '_cls_modified_context'):
        cls._cls_modified_context.disable()
        delattr(cls, '_cls_modified_context')
    if hasattr(cls, '_cls_overridden_context'):
        cls._cls_overridden_context.disable()
        delattr(cls, '_cls_overridden_context')
    super().tearDownClass()
```

Al ejecutar los test obtengo el siguiente resultado

```
System check identified 56 issues (0 silenced).
..E
======================================================================
ERROR: tearDownClass (apps.core.tests.HistTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\proyect\env\Lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1220, in tearDownClass
    super().tearDownClass()
File "D:\proyect\env\Lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 230, in tearDownClass
    cls._remove_databases_failures()
File "D:\proyect\env\Lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 226, in _remove_databases_failures
    setattr(connection, name, method.wrapped)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'wrapped'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 2.074s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

La recomendación que encontré buscando una forma de solucionar este problema fue sobre escribir el método e ignorar el contenido

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    pass
```

Sin embargo considero que no es lo ideal ya que como lo mencioné se estaría ignorando el proceso y no es una solución como tal.

Si alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este inconveniente, gradezco la ayuda u orientación que me puedan brindar

Answer (score 1):

Para resolverlo agregé la conexión con la cual deseo trabajar en las peticiones como variable de entorno, en el proceso de finalización valido la existencia de la conexión y la remuevo antes de que se procese la función `wrapped`

```
import decouple

from django.db import connections
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class CustomAPITestCase(APITestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.id = decouple.config('CONN_ID')

    @classmethod
    def _remove_databases_failures(cls) -> None:
        if cls.conn_id in connections.databases:
            connections.databases.pop(cls.conn_id)

        for alias in connections:
            if alias in cls.databases:
                continue
            connection = connections[alias]
            for name, _ in cls._disallowed_connection_methods:
                method = getattr(connection, name)
                setattr(connection, name, method.wrapped)

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        super().setUp()
        self.conn_id = self.__class__.conn_id
```